# Installing bob face recognition package on google colab

Tags: machine-learning, google-colaboratory, face-recognition

I wanted to install the bob face recognition packages and I'm facing several problems installing them on Colab. Is Google Colab notebook itself an environment? If anyone knows how to install bob on colab please let me know. 
Thanks in advance. :)

I keep getting the following error while installing bob:
DistributionNotFound  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 import bob.bio.face